# How to check if a remote server supports PHP?

Tags: php

I often have clients who do not know if their server supports PHP (their website is HTML web site). At the moment, I send them hello.php file, they upload it and then I check it remotely if their server supports PHP. As you see this takes day or two and it's just a waste of time.

Can I myself any how check if their server supports PHP (via web browser or console tool)? If the domain is for example www.my-client.com, what would be the syntax?

Thanks

PS. I have an access to Linux console so I could use it as well

Comment: I've yet to see a *nix server that doesn't have PHP installed, it's usually IIS (Windows) that you'll need to upload a PHP file with `phpinfo();` in it to see if it works and can then show you what is available / enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Darin Dimitrov says some Servers promote the versions of the uses software.  You can use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to view the HTTP Header of a response.

```
> curl -I http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 17 May 2011 10:04:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10 with Suhosin-Patch
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Yeah, curl is cool Unix command. The only problem is that the output of a HTML based site is rather large and I have to save it info TXT file. But as I said, curl is great tool.

Comment: `curl -I` only prints the Response Header

Answer (score 7):

The best you could do is send an HTTP request to this server `http://www.my-client.com` and inspect response HTTP headers. In some cases depending on the server there might be clues. For example here's how the response HTTP headers look like in [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for http://joomla.org:

[image]

Comment: is this also true for .html files?

Comment: @zaf, the server could still send information about what modules are installed. But I insist: this is not reliable, as I said it could give clues. If you see the clues this doesn't mean anything, it's just an indication. The web server can send whatever response headers he wants.

Comment: just did a check on my setup and for static files the 'Server' parameter includes PHP info. Of course, like you say its not reliable.

Comment: Excellent idea. I totally forgot on FireBug. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Can also try with

```
http://www.example.com/?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42
```

Some servers will respond with a PHP image then. If you have shell access, it is more reliable to test whether php in installed directly on the system though. Whether PHP exposes if it is installed via this Easter Egg or via the Response Headers can be disabled in the PHP.ini.

#### Read more at

- [`php_logo_guid` — Gets the logo guid](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.php-logo-guid.php) and
- [`expose_php` ini setting](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php)

> Decides whether PHP may expose the fact that it is installed on the server (e.g. by adding its signature to the Web server header). It is no security threat in any way, but it makes it possible to determine whether you use PHP on your server or not.

Comment: It is not a complete solution, because this Easter-Egg behavior can be blocked.

Comment: @Tomasz I never said its a complete solution. Updated the answer to clarify that in case it wasnt already obvious.

Comment: I never said that you've said that. :) I only felt the need to clarify it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Not very reliable (but a quick check) is requesting a non existing path (404) returns information about the server and its setup.
For example, on my machine I get the following in the footer which I could parse for 'PHP':

> Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l
>   PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Darin Dimitrov's answer I can say that you could read WHOIS information about the domain and detect where it is being hosted. Then, if you identify the hoster, simply check what features he offers.

Comment: I could, but this is another "long process". Anyway thanks for suggestion

Comment: This is relatively short process - client tell you the domain name, you go to, for example: http://whois.domaintools.com/ , enter the domain, "search" and the answer is on your screen.